# GTK text box number entry

Tags: c, linux, gtk, special-characters

I am trying to create a text box in GTK+3.0 (using C, in Linux) that can be read from as a double, where this double will be plugged into an equation and then returned in a different box.

So my question is: what is the best way to create a text box that can be typed into, and then how do I read it as a double?

I am currently trying to use `gtk_entry_new()` to initialize and - after a few intermediary steps - `*gtk_entry_get_text` to read.

My read line currently looks like this:

```
double y = (double)*gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(input_y));
```

I keep getting y as a pointer, and the `*gtk_entry_get_text(...)` is of format const gchar*

I believe the best way is to convert `const gchar*` into `double`, but how?

Answer (score 1):

$ man atof

```
NAME
   atof - convert a string to a double

SYNOPSIS
   #include <stdlib.h>

   double atof(const char *nptr);

DESCRIPTION
   The atof() function converts the initial portion of the string
   pointed to by nptr to double.  The behavior is the same as

       strtod(nptr, (char **) NULL);

   except that atof() does not detect errors.

RETURN VALUE
   The converted value.
```

thus:

```
double y = atof(gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(input_y)));
```